# Cakephp 2.4 version not updating data in the datsbase

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am creating app for reservation which will create request for pickup and for that i am sending all fields to my action of request Controller but that is not saving data into database. i am unable to figure out the issue in it. The code for that controller is

```
 public function create() {
    $this->layout='';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Request->create();
        $get_Count = $this->Request->find('count');
        $get_Count=$get_Count+1;
        $this->request->data['Latitude'] = floatval($this->request->data['Latitude']);
        $this->request->data['Longitude'] = floatval($this->request->data['Longitude']);
        $this->request->data['Country'] = $this->request->data['Country'];
        $this->request->data['City'] = $this->request->data['City'];
        $this->request->data['Postal_Code'] = $this->request->data['Postal_Code'];
        $this->request->data['Mobile_Number'] = $this->request->data['Mobile_Number'];
        $this->request->data['Current_Status'] = (int) $this->request->data['Current_Status'];
        $this->request->data['Created_Date'] = date("d/m/Y");
        $this->request->data['Modified']=false;
        $this->request->data['Total_Km']=0.0;
        $this->request->data['Price_Per_Km']=0;
        $this->request->data['Total_Price']=0;
        $this->request->data['Type'] = (int) $this->request->data['Type'];
        //$this->request->data['Id']=$get_Count;
        $p=(int) $this->request->data['Passenger'];;
        $this->request->data['Passenger'] = $p;
        $this->request->data['Driver']=0;       
        $this->request->data['Pick_Up'] = $this->request->data['Pick_Up'];
        $this->request->data['Drop_Off'] = $this->request->data['Drop_Off'];
        $this->request->data['Modified_By'] = 0;
         if ($this->Request->save($this->request->data)) {
             $this->request->data['Status']=1;
             $this->request->data['Request_Id']=$get_Count;
             echo json_encode($this->request->data);
             return;

        } else {
             $this->request->data['Status']=0;
             echo json_encode($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The request could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

It's Model is as

```
   <?php
 App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
 /**
 * Request Model
 *
 */
 class Request extends AppModel {

 /**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
*/
public $validate = array(
    'Country' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or        'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'City' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Postal_Code' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Mobile_Number' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Current_Status' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Created_Date' => array(
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array('date'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Modified' => array(
        'boolean' => array(
            'rule' => array('boolean'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Price_Per_Km' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Type' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Passenger' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Driver' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Pick_Up' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Drop_Off' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'Modified_By' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);
```

}

Android Output in LogCat is

> 12-11 01:20:17.073: I/System.out(26832): Setting the contents of the Reader
>   12-11 01:20:17.133: I/System.out(26832): {"Latitude":31.4685541,"Longitude":74.3374621,"Country":"Pakistan","City":"Lahore","Postal_Code":"54700","Mobile_Number":"03227658594","Current_Status":3,"Type":1,"Passenger":1,"Pick_Up":"uugfdjgsdh","Drop_Off":"vjjffjjffjkkfg","Created_Date":"10/12/2013","Modified":false,"Total_Km":0,"Price_Per_Km":0,"Total_Price":0,"Id":1,"Driver":0,"Modified_By":0,"Status":0}
>   12-11 01:20:17.133: I/System.out(26832): I am in try block of json final result reading

I am getting the Status 0 on Android Device.Its View is empty.

Comment: Try `debug($this->Request->validationErrors);` .  There's a strong likelihood saving failed because your data did not validate for some reason, so trying to print the validationErrors may tell you something.

Comment: Good idea to remove excess commented code.  The easier you can make it on people trying to help the better :)

Comment: @Kai your one line saved my a-lot of time actually it was having issue in created date coulmn.Thanks